# Nested quotes in SQLite request issue

Tags: sqlite, actionscript-3, air

In my AIR app I use SQLite database. And at some point I need to pass request with quotes. 
I'm using a regexp to escape them like this:

```
public static function escapeQuotes(str:String):String
{
    return str.replace(/"/g, '\\"');
}
```

But somehow this doesn't help. I still get the error.
My reequest looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Prof_Eng_Russ WHERE english || english_keywords LIKE "%something \"name\"%"
```

And I get this error:
**Error #2044: Unhandled SQLErrorEvent:. errorID=3115, operation=execute , message=Error #3115: SQL Error. , details=near 'name': syntax error**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL does not use a backslash for escaping.
Escaped quotes would be doubled, but it is easier to use parameters:

```
sql = new SQLStatement();
sql.sqlConnection = ...;
sql.text = "SELECT * FROM Prof_Eng_Russ WHERE english || english_keywords LIKE @pattern";
sql.parameters["@pattern"] = "%something \"name\"%";
```

(This is an ActionScript string that is escaped according to ActionScript rules.)

Comment: thanks. But I get this error: Unhandled SQLErrorEvent:. errorID=3115, operation=execute , message=Error #3115: SQL Error. , details='@pattern' parameter name(s) found in parameters property but not in the SQL specified.

Comment: Yes, that's my faultm I had to call .clearParameters() after .execute.